# Strawberry Perl not recognising special variable for OSNAME

Tags: perl, ansi, strawberry-perl

I recently upgraded Strawberry Perl from version 5.14.1.1-32bit to 5.24.0-64bit on my PC running Windows 7.  I have a perl script I run under both Windows and Linux, and when I was using the old version the command

```
use if $^O eq 'MSWin32' , 'Win32::Console::ANSI';
```

worked, but now that I've upgraded I get the error message

```
Unrecognized character \x0F; marked by <-- HERE after use if $<-- HERE near column9 at p:\bin\abc.pl line 31.
```

Does anyone know what changed, and how I can get the new version of Strawberry Perl to accept the command?  Thanks in advance to all who respond.

Comment: Is that a `^` and `O` or a `ctrl-O` character?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code contains the [Shift In](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_Out_and_Shift_In_characters) control character (0x0F), also known as "Control-O", instead of the characters `^` and `O`. This works in older versions of Perl but was [deprecated in version 5.20.0](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5200delta.html#Literal-control-characters-in-variable-names):

> **Literal control characters in variable names**
>
> This deprecation affects things like $\cT, where \cT is a literal control (such as a `NAK` or `NEGATIVE ACKNOWLEDGE` character) in the source code. Surprisingly, it appears that originally this was intended as the canonical way of accessing variables like $^T, with the caret form only being added as an alternative.
>
> The literal control form is being deprecated for two main reasons. It has what are likely unfixable bugs, such as $\cI not working as an alias for $^I, and their usage not being portable to non-ASCII platforms: While $^T will work everywhere, \cT is whitespace in EBCDIC. [perl #119123]

[As of 5.24.0](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5240delta.html#ASCII-characters-in-variable-names-must-now-be-all-visible), using a variable name containing non-graphical ASCII control characters results in a syntax error.

Comment: I changed it as you suggested, and it worked like a charm.  Thanks!

Comment: I think the talk about `"\cO"` being ASCII `SI` and the link to Wikipedia is irrelevant noise. On the other hand, the link to perldelta 5.24 is central and should be at the top

Comment: I for one am *not* surprised that the original intent was for it to be an actual control character. That was the sort of thing that was cool about perl in the beginning - its lack of unnecessary limitations. Control characters in a variable name? Why not! (Having to care about EBCDIC has never been and will never be cool)